# Django application not logging tornado daemon uwsgi

Tags: django, python-2.7, tornado, uwsgi, django-logging

I am trying to log my django application. This works fine (I see all other logs in the logfile) unless I try to 
log my uWSGI daemonized processes. I am new to using a daemon, is there a reason why it would log differently?

I am using in uwsgi.yaml:

```
env: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=application.settings
module: application.wsgi
log-master: True
log-syslog: uwsgi
attach-daemon: /opt/application/bin/tornading
```

This is my Logging in the settings module:

```
LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/application.log',
            'maxBytes': 1 * 1024 * 1024,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'application': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

tornading.py starts an IOloop instance and a tornado consumer:

```
import logging
import settings
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    app = tornado.web.Application(BroadcastRouter.urls)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(port=settings.TORNADO_PORT, address=settings.TORNADO_HOST)
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    consumer = communication.TornadoConsumer(ioloop, BroadcastConnection.on_rabbit_message)
    consumer.connect()

    LOGGER.debug('Hello world')

    ioloop.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have also tried `LOGGER = logging.getLogger('application')` and still no logging from tornading.py

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Django - you don't need configure logger, because Django make it themselves when load.

When you use Tornado there is no autoconfig loggger. Try to config manually.

```
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)
```

Also for future reading: [15.8. logging.config — Logging configuration](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html)

Comment: Thank you. Actually my mystake was that I was import the settings from the wrong app and with this I was able to spot it.

Comment: Glad to help you @ffc